# IllegalStateException: Webpack exited prematurely

Tags: java, node.js, npm, webpack, vaadin

I have a project I'm working on with Vaadin 14.4.10, Node.js 14.16.1 and had no problems with it until now. The only difference is that I was playing around in a local branch with it and lifted the Vaadin version up to 23.3.6.

Since new Vaadin versions build with Vite instead of Webpack, my only guess can be that it screwed up my system files, because upon returning to the develop branch where we use Vaadin 14, I can't start the frontend part of my app getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Webpack exited prematurely
    com.vaadin.flow.server.DevModeHandler.doStartWebpack(DevModeHandler.java:657)
    com.vaadin.flow.server.DevModeHandler.doStartDevModeServer(DevModeHandler.java:583)
    com.vaadin.flow.server.DevModeHandler.runOnFutureComplete(DevModeHandler.java:530)
    com.vaadin.flow.server.DevModeHandler.lambda$new$0(DevModeHandler.java:146)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.exec(CompletableFuture.java:479)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec$$$capture(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
```

Any suggestions on what can I try to solve this?

I'm using IntelliJ and I've already tried `mvn clean install`, `npm install`, `npm install webpack`, `mvn clean process-resources`, downloaded the latest LTS version of node.js and tried cleaning and reinstalling again, pulled the project in a new workspace and then tried cleaning and reinstalling again, deleted the `node_modules` folder along with `package.json`, `package-lock.json`, `webpack.config.js` and `webpack.generated.js` and then ran `npm install` but nothing I've tried so far worked.

**Edit:
Today I've tried running the Vaadin 14 tutorial from Vaadin official website, but it produced the same error - got whitelabel page with this:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Webpack exited prematurely
com.vaadin.flow.server.ServiceException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Webpack exited prematurely
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleExceptionDuringRequest(VaadinService.java:1596)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1559)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:247)
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringServlet.service(SpringServlet.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:711)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:313)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Webpack exited prematurely
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.DevModeHandler.doStartWebpack(DevModeHandler.java:657)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.DevModeHandler.doStartDevModeServer(DevModeHandler.java:583)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.DevModeHandler.runOnFutureComplete(DevModeHandler.java:530)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.DevModeHandler.lambda$new$0(DevModeHandler.java:146)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:478)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've got it to work.

In addition to deleting all of the npm generated files (`node_modules` folder, `package-lock.json`, `webpack.config.js` and `webpack.generated.js`), it is necessary to delete the `.vaadin` folder which is placed in `C:\Users\<username>\` folder. After that, I've hit mvn clean install and the project ran fine.

I believe that the problem was caused by the leftover files in the `.vaadin` folder from v23 that weren't properly cleaned.